# Stanford NLP: Understanding the Tregex

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

Firstly, Im not sure what Im looking for is **tregex** but im going to try my best to explain my question.

What I want to do is, lets say I've a custom grammar like below.

```
VP -> V + NP + PP
NP -> NN | PRP
PP -> IN + NP
```

**V** is all verbs meaning it doesn't matter if its past or present etc.
**+** means concat
**|** means or

And I've a string of postags like below.

```
VBZ PRP IN NN
```

What I want to do is to check if this string is **valid** for the grammar above. I want to do that using the Stanford NLP API since my project uses it. I know I can use a compiler like **jacc** but I want to stick with Stanford NLP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that Tregex doesn't do what you want. It's a pattern matcher over tree structures. It isn't a parser. In theory the Stanford Parser can do parsing with any grammar, but in practice, there is no support for hand-written grammars. So you would be best off using a tool like jacc, JavaCC or ANTLR.

Comment: Thank you. I think  I'll go with **jacc** then.